# intercom-php API - creating conversation using an email returns 400 bad request

Tags: php, api, http, http-status-code-400, intercom

**intercom-php version:** 4.2

**Intercom API version:** 1.4

**PHP version:** 7.3

**Expected behavior:**
I am trying (as per the documentation here: https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v1.4/reference#user-or-contact-initiated-conversation) to initiate a conversation using an email address, like so:

```
$response = $client->messages->create([
    'message_type' => 'inapp',
    'body' => 'Hello....',
    'from' => [
        'type' => 'contact',
        'email' => 'example_email_address@example.com',
    ]
]);
```

I am expecting this to create the conversation, as the documentation states:

"The sending user or lead is identified by their user_id, email or id values in the from field, along with a type field value of user or contact."

**Actual behavior:**
This returns a 400 bad request response, if 'email' is used in the from field.

**Logs:**
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Http\Client\Common\Exception\ClientErrorException: Bad Request in .../php-http/client-common/src/Plugin/ErrorPlugin.php:7

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening due to

- multiple records matching the same email
- and the PHP library not showing the full error message

If multiple records match, you will need to use `user_id` / `id` instead of `email`. It should match an existing unique record for it to work

**Check for multiple records matching**

- Log into your Intercom app and search for the email in question
- `contact` in the API corresponds to `Leads` in the web interface
  [image: multiple records with the same email]

**View raw error messages**

- [Get your Access Token](https://developers.intercom.com/building-apps/docs/authentication-types#section-how-to-get-your-access-token)
- Make a `curl` request via the terminal / command line (replace `YOUR_INTERCOM_ACCESS_TOKEN` value with your value) (raw request can be copied from the docs https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v1.4/reference#user-or-contact-initiated-conversation )

```
$ curl https://api.intercom.io/messages \
-XPOST \
-H 'Authorization:Bearer YOUR_INTERCOM_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "from": {
    "type": "contact",
    "email": "me@example.com"
  },
  "body": "Hey"
}'
{"type":"error.list","request_id":"003858akvkngsbrdj3h0","errors":[{"code":"multiple_users","message":"Multiple contact profiles found with the provided email. Please be more specific using user_id."}]}
```

**Finding `id` / `user_id` value**

- Click into the record in the web interface
- `id` should be in the URL `https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/your_app_id/users/LONG_STRING_WHICH_IS_THE_ID/all-conversations` the format should look something like this `5fe8c9742114721c54d22754`
- `user_id` should be the "User ID" attribute value

[image: Finding id / user_id value]